# Select from table group by id where all records in that group have a flag = false

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Table:

```
ID|Col1|Col2|
1 |abc |1   |
2 |abc |0   |
3 |xyz |0   |
4 |xyz |0   |
5 |jkl |1   |
```

**Q1.** I want to return a list of records grouped by Col1 where all of the records in that group have Col2 = 0. I don't mind if it returns all of them (record 3 and 4) or just unique one(e.g. just 'xyz').

**Q2.** I also would like to get a list of records grouped by Col1 where any of the records in that group have Col2 = 1 (in this case 'abc' and 'jkl')

Comment: Do you want ID in your result or just col1?

Comment: Don't mind but col1 is all that I require

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select col1
from your_table
group by col1
having sum(case when col2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

and

```
select col1
from your_table
group by col1
having sum(case when col2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

And another ways, using EXISTS and sub-queries:

```
select *
from your_table
where not exists (select * from your_table t2 where col1 = t2.col1 and col2 <> 0)
```

And

```
select *
from your_table
where exists (select * from your_table t2 where col1 = t2.col1 and col2 = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might helps you

```
  declare @t table(a char(1), b int)
 insert into  @t values ('a',0),('b',1),('a',0),('b',0)
```

for first

```
 select distinct * from @t
 where a not in (select a from @t where b=1)
```

for second

```
  select distinct * from @t
  where a in (select a from @t where b=1)
```

---

vote this if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try Conditional Aggregation:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(ID INT, Col1 VARCHAR(30), Col2 INT)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
(1,'abc',1),
(2,'abc',0),
(3,'xyz',0),
(4,'xyz',0),
(5,'jkl',1)


SELECT Col1
FROM   @table
GROUP  BY Col1
HAVING SUM(CASE
             WHEN Col2 = 0 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) = COUNT(*)

SELECT Col1
FROM   @table
GROUP  BY Col1
HAVING SUM(CASE
             WHEN Col2 = 1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already marked another answer, but you can even tune it, because in this particular case you don't need cases in having clause. Actually you will need cases when col2 is not numeric type, say varchar

```
Select col1 from table
group by col1
having sum(col2)=0

Select col1 from table
group by col1
having sum(col2)>0
```